# Default namespace of models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

After upgrading my Rails app, I have run into a problem where the name of one of my models are conflicting with another class in Rails, namely `Configuration`.

Is there a way for me to (from a controller) explicit use my model class `Configuration` instead of `ActiveSupport::Configurable::Configuration`? What is the default namespace for my models?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `::Configuration` to call your class. It means that you're referring to the constant `Configuration` from the toplevel namespace. But I think it's annoying. You can rename your class to avoid this.

Comment: Of course I plan on either putting it into a namespace or renaming it. But until then, thank you!